# Firebase Realtime Database load issues / brownout

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

We experience intermittent, seemingly random brownouts of a firebase realtime database. We are beginning to shard our data into multiple databases, however, we are not sure this will solve our problem. It appears to us that firebase cannot scale to meet our needs in terms of doing frequent writes to a specific data set.

We sync data from a third-party data source in cycles (every 4-10 minutes, 1000 active jobs). Each update has the potential to change a few thousand nodes in firebase, most of which lie pretty low. However, most of the time the number of low-level nodes changed is much lower. We do differential updates on the sync'd data in order to allow very small writes to the lower-level nodes. This helps prevent our users from downloading a ton of additional data. We also batch all of our updates per cycle into only a handful of writes, between 10-20 (not sure of the performance impact of a batched write to multiple nodes vs. a write to a single node).

Here is an image of the database load graph, which includes some sharding:
[Database Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9xvi.png)

The "blue" line is our "main" database. The "orange line" is a database containing only the data that requires many writes, as described above. Currently, the main (blue) database is supporting normal operations, including reads/writes, etc.. The shard (orange) database is only handling writes. The mirror of these is pretty indicative of a "write" load issue, given that a large percentage of writes occurs in the morning.

At times, the database load reaches 100% and remains in this state for 30+ minutes.

Please let me know if I can expand on anything or explain anything in more detail. Would appreciate any suggestions on debugging strategies or explanations as to why this may be occurring.

We are actively refactoring a lot of code to mitigate this issue, however, it is not obvious what the main driver is.